# pass parameter through selectors in component Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I actually want to apply a specific class on button (which is in btn.component.html) if it is passed through the selector. 
my selector is

```
<btn></btn>
```

btn.component.ts is

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'btn',
  template: require('./btn.component.html')
})

export class BtnComponent { }
```

btn.component.html is

```
<button>Okay</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by if it's passed through a selector ?

Comment: i mean i want to pass a parameter through selector in component something like 

<btn [parameter]="redBtn"></btn>

and it should send this parameter to component, where I can use it

Comment: This is ridiculous , why can't you just read the documentation ? this is the first thing you'd learn in Angular2.

Comment: I beg to differ. The first you learn is how to make components and modules. And please answer if you can, but no need to look down on the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass class name as params like :

```
<btn className="btn-class"></btn>
```

//Component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'btn',
  template: `<button [class]="className">Okay</button>`
})    
export class BtnComponent {
  @Input() className :string = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ranakrunal9. Working good. One more small question. I am not able to put any other static class to the button in btn.component.html.

Comment: To use static class you have to change its HTML to `<button class="static-class" [ngClass]="[className]">Okay</button>`

Comment: Working awesome!! Thanks @ranakrunal9